# Cleaning procedure for electronic tools and equipment?

Tags: equipment

I recently had to work from an old building which was in poor repair in order to get access to three phase power.

I stripped down the room etc. so that there was a bare concrete floor but still after working there I feel some of my equipment needs a good clean to remove any trace elements that may have got on it.  It may sound daft but having worked in clean rooms, etc., cleanliness is very important to me.

Can anyone recommend a good cleaning method for my equipment (solder station, oscilloscope, wire cutters, tweezers, etc.)?

Comment: Stainless can be washed, electrical items blow off or vacuum with ESD safe vacuum.

Comment: @MadHatter thanks, I guess I mean a step further as in what solution is advised to remove potential contaminants.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused, for washable equipment something with a detergent would be good. If you're trying to get equipment to be clean room level clean, that's just not going to happen. No company should allow equipment that's been in a demolition area into a clean room. New equipment preferably clean room rated should be purchased for use there.

Comment: @Madhatter to be fair I use the equipment for prototyping, fixturing, etc. and it wasn't quite a demolition area in which I was working, however I have high standards and do feel like throwing circa $4k equipment out and restarting!

Comment: What is the real concern here. If you cleaned it off, what "contamination" are you worried about? Have you ever been to China and seen a Fab there? Your equipment is probably way cleaner then what is used to make large amounts of consumer and industrial equipment. If you describe the contamination maybe someone can help more, but at this point it sounds like you are worried about the same level of dust and particles that are in common air. Honestly for electrical assembly you do not need clean room environments, even for super high voltage, everything is just cleaned and coated.

Answer (score 1):

for electrical equipment Follow manufacturer's reccomendatuions (usually wipe with a damp cloth) blow dust out with compressed air.

for simple tools wash and lubricate as required.